# how to include images,scripts that are in default folder of views in web2py

Tags: javascript

I have an image in the default folder of views as an example in the below link (http://127.0.0.1:8000/cooking_recipes/default/images/nav-logo.png) and even some scripts in the same folder.that is because I am using ready-made template for my website.So how coould I say web2py that those are just images and scripts and not html views? I found that web2py is treating them as views and giving back a html page with the source code view-source:http://127.0.0.1:8000/cooking_recipes/default/images/nav-logo.png

```
<html><body><h1>invalid function (default/images)</h1></body></html>
```